# Android: Cannot disconnect apps correcty from Google

Tags: android, api, google-play, google-play-games

When testing my app's leaderboards/achievements and sign-in flow (for Google Play Game Services), I used to be able to go into the 'Google Settings' app, then into 'Connected Apps', click on my app and there I would get the option to 'Disconnect' as well as 'Also delete all activities on Google' Like the following:

[image]

However, something seems to have changed (not in my code, as the same apps now can't disconnect) - now when I attempt to disconnect, I simply get this message:

[image]

Now, to test my sign-in flow for bugs, I would like to be able to make the app 'forget' it has ever connected to Google Play Game Services, so it asks for permission again -  [(please see my previous question here for which the answer used to work)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80874/resetting-google-play-games-services-so-app-forgets-it-previously-connected-s). Previously I was presented with the first diagram & this worked if I simply clicked 'disconnect' - Clicking the checkbox, ('Also delete all your............') also reset my achievements, which was great when I needed to debug them.

Most other apps I try to disconnect from give the following message, which is the first message minus the checkbox:

[image]

Does anyone know if the requirements to be able to let the user completely disconnect from your app have changed and why my apps only give me a basic messasge now?

I currently connect to GPGS like this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
// No other APIs needed
.build();       

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Permissins in the Manifest (if relevant) are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I've tried to be as throurough as possible, but if any other information is required, please ask.

Comment: I think a Googler or someone who experience this scenario can only help you about this issue. So I suggest you to try to contact the support for the Google Play game service about this matter. This [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/6097563?hl=en#ts=6097687%2C6097659) can help you to do that. Also, make sure that you follow the code given in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect#disconnect_accounts) on how to properly signing out the users and disconnecting the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Here, there seems to have no way to disconnect some app using a google settings thing, neither google+, the only way I found was this url:
https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Also, I tested with a few games, to disconnect it and also to erase all its data on the smartphone, and as soon I started the game, and allowed a new google connection for it, everything was restored. From that I came to 2 possible reasons:
1) After disconnecting, the saved data on our google account for that app is not deleted, and neither deletable by us, so I guess only the app developer could do that.
2) If it is deleted, the app developer may still have a saved copy, and as soon we reconnect, that is restored.

The option would be to wait for some duration of time, after disconnecting, so the app developer also deletes their backup based on our inactivity. Still have to test it though, and may take months.